# How to debug client-side in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code

According to the [Microsoft Documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging), the Visual Studio Code debugger should be able to debug typescript and javascript.

Problematically, they only provide examples for server side apps using node or python. Intellisense only suggests server languages.

Is it possible to debug client-side typescript or javascript apps with the Visual Studio Code debugger?

**launch.json**

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible Node.js debug attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "type":"node"      <-- what if I'm building a JS / TS app?
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${file}",
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceRoot}/out/**/*.js"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40045078/vscode-gulp-grunt-script-running-vscode-chrome-debugger-extension/40096464#40096464 using the chrome debugger extension.

Answer (score 4):

You have to install one (or more) of the browser debugger extensions: [Chrome](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome), [Firefox](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hbenl.vscode-firefox-debug), [iOS Web](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.debugger-for-ios-web) or [Edge](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.debugger-for-edge).

Then you can use launch configuration like this for Chrome:

```
{
    "type": "chrome",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Launch Chrome",
    "url": "http://localhost:8080",
    "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
}
```

Depending on you build workflow, you may have to do some additional steps to get source maps to work.

Comment: Thanks! That is awesome!

Comment: where to make those configuration?

Comment: Yes, that's right, but the "url" parameter set to "http://localhost:8080" means an intermediate web-server must be launched. How to establish and setup it in Windows? Is there an easy guide?