# vscode launch webserver before start debugging

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

My intention is to start automatically an internal webserver (using express extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Compulim.vscode-express) with a launch configuration in the preLaunchTask property. For debugging I'm using Debugger for Chrome in vscode.

Express offers vscode commands like 'express.hostWorkspace' or 'express.hostWorkspaceWithRandomPort'.
I tried to config this vscode commands in a task and use this task in the preLaunchTask property, but it doesn't worked.

Is it possibile to run vscode commands as a task and use it in preLaunchTask or is there an other possibility?

Comment: Have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40045078/vscode-gulp-grunt-script-running-vscode-chrome-debugger-extension/40096464#40096464  You could run a gulp/grunt task to start your server as part of your launch configuration.

Comment: Thanks Mark.
I didn't find this question when I searched for my problem. Moreover I don't know if it is possible to run a vscode command in a gulp task. Nevertheless it is an oppertunity also to run express via own code. I will try it

Comment: It seems to be that it is problematic, because the job never terminates. So if you run it as preLaunchTask the follow-up action (loading the debug browser) is not done.