# How to Debug JavaScript in Visual Studio Code with live-server Running

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, npm-live-server

Trying to debug a simple HTML and JavaScript project in Visual Studio Code. In the VS Code terminal window, 'live-server' is used to launch the 'index.html'. In VS Code, the 'Debugger for Chrome' is installed and configured. Even after the page is launched in the Chrome browser, the debugger will not attach and give the error message 'Cannot connect to runtime process, timeout after 10000 ms - (reason: Cannot connect to the target: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9222).'.

launch.json

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "attach",
        "name": "Attach to Chrome",
        "port": 9222,
        "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "urlFilter": "http://localhost:8080"
    },
    {
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Chrome against index.html",
        "file": "${workspaceRoot}/index.html"
    }
]
```

The shortcut to Chrome is modified to include `--remote-debugging-port=9222`

Is it possible to use 'live-server' and debug or set breakpoints in VS Code on the JavaScript file?

Comment: It's a little old but the workflow (uses browserSync) at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40045078/vscode-gulp-grunt-script-running-vscode-chrome-debugger-extension/40096464#40096464 may help.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I added a new section in launch.json to launch with sourcemaps as you have in your example and it worked.

Comment: Great, glad it works.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Works for me:

1. Install and activate [**Live Server**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) extension on your VS Code.
2. Press **F5** and select **Chrome**:

[image]

3. Check your **Live Server** port* and change the generated `launch.json`

[image]

4. Set your break points, run **Live Server** and press **F5**:

[image]

5. Enjoy :)

---

- **To check your Live Server port:**

1. Install Live Server & reload VS Code.
2. Go to Preferences > Extensions > Live Server Config
3. Scroll down to find Settings: Port and click "Edit in settings.json". Then you'll see the port number.

Comment: Would be helpful to know how to do this step: Check your [Live Server] port. Install Live Server & reload VS Code. Go to Preferences > Extensions > Live Server Config - scroll down to find Settings: Port and click "Edit in settings.json". Then you'll see the port number.

Comment: Step 1 has a link to a deprecated vscode extension. Maybe you can address the issue in your answer.

Comment: (I removed the step 1 Timo was referring to as it is no longer needed)