# how to use Chrome Debugger with live server in Visual Studio Code

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am currently using [Visual Code Studio](https://code.visualstudio.com/) and I have [Live Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) and [Debugger for Chrome](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome) extensions installed.

I am testing a simple .html file to see how the debug is working on VS Code as I am newly switching to.

[image]

I changed the url to `"url": "http://localhost:5500"` in `launch.json` file to use the Live Server port.

Now the issue : when I click go live, the browser opens `http://127.0.0.1:5500/debug.html` but when I click F5 to debug I am redirected only to `http://127.0.0.1:5500`. Is there a way to redirect to full path in debug mode instead of adjusting the url manually each time to `http://127.0.0.1:5500/'File Path'` ? and if it's possible the page will be opened in new tab not new chrome window.

[image]

Any suggestions please what am I missing in my setup ? I followed multiple threads and documentations but still can't make it work, example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46945784/how-to-debug-javascript-in-visual-studio-code-with-live-server-running) and [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-set-up-the-debugger-for-chrome-extension-in-visual-studio-code-c0b3e5937c01/).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should define the `.html` file.

Here is an example:

```
{
    "port": 8181,
    "host": "0.0.0.0",
    "root": "/public",
    "open": false,
    "ignore": "scss,my/templates",
    "file": "index.html",
    "wait": 1000,
    "mount": [
        ["/components", "./node_modules"],
        ["/image", "./myImageFolder"]
    ],
    "logLevel": 2
}
```

I hope that helps! Please let me know if there is anything else, I can help you with.

Comment: that's the live server config file. i was making some googling and it looks like to set up the rule on launch.json on the debug side. I am not sure about your approach how i should update my settings based on your recommendation

Comment: In the `.json` file, add a key with the name `"file"` and assign the value of `"index.html"`.

Comment: I am doing it that way. but i want it to detect dynamically the name of file instead of writting it by myself manually each time. instead of using "file":"login.html" or "file":"datatable.html"... it will be sth like "file":"{my_current_file_in_debug}"

Comment: Check out variables in the Visual Studio Code (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference). I think for your case that would be `${file}`.